# sql join не верный результат

Tags: sql, join

имеем две таблицы
1) **partsm**:

```
|Столбец|Тип|Null|По умолчанию
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|Нет|
|number|varchar(255)|Нет|
|name|varchar(255)|Нет|
|description|varchar(255)|Нет|
|quantity|varchar(255)|Нет|
|sid|varchar(255)|Нет|
|mapid|int(11)|Нет|
|man|varchar(255)|Нет|
```

2) **carsm_partsm**

```
|Столбец|Тип|Null|По умолчанию
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|Нет|
|partsm_id|int(11)|Нет|
|carsm_id|int(11)|Нет|
```

необходимо получить все `carsm_partsm.carsm_id` которые соответствуют `partsm.id=carsm_partsm.partsm_id` в виде `carsm_partsm.carsm_id` через запятую, с условием `where partsm.number`

вот мой запрос:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',',carsm_partsm.carsm_id)) as _carid   
FROM partsm   
INNER JOIN carsm_partsm ON partsm.id = carsm_partsm.partsm_id    
WHERE partsm.number = "807020010"
```

он срабатывает но почемуто часть данных не верная, не все соответствия находятся.

Comment: А зачем CONCAT_WS. `GROUP_CONCAT(carsm_partsm.carsm_id)` должно быть достаточно. А если что то не находится, сделайте просто `select *` и посмотрите чего именно не хватает. потому как запрос в общем то выглядит правильно, если что то не так - значит что то не так в данных

Comment: в данных все 100% так, руками находится то что не выдается после данного запроса. Если честно не понимаю разницу между CONCAT_WS и просто CONCAT :)

Comment: concat_ws объединяет два и более параметров через указанный разделитель. concat просто объединяет 2 и более строк без разделителей. К group_concat который собирает значения из нескольких строк они никакого отношения не имеют

Comment: Если запрос действительно что то не выводит, попробуйте сделать контрольный пример на каком нибудь sqlfiddle.com на котором будет видно исходные данные и "неправильный" результат. Не видя контрольного примера сказать что тут не так невозможно

Comment: изменил запрос на SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(',',carsm_partsm.carsm_id) as _carid FROM partsm INNER JOIN carsm_partsm ON partsm.id = carsm_partsm.partsm_id WHERE partsm.number = "807020010" ничего не изменилось естественно

Comment: Я сказал сделать `GROUP_CONCAT(carsm_partsm.carsm_id)` - это буквально, надо написать именно так, символ в символ, зачем вы добавляете к строке еще одну запятую ?

Comment: вот залил немного данных в fiddle в частности проблема с тем что из моей базы не выводится carsm_partsm.carsm_id=1802 но на самом деле такая запись есть в carsm_partsm и есть такой id как partsm.id залил в fiddle именно эту часть ибо много данных он лить не дает, а у меня только в carsm_partsm ~9 миллионов строк и в partsm 1.7 миллиона http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90b389/2/0 в данном варианте конечно он выдал 1802 без проблем, не пойму почему из моей базы нет этого ид в списке, другие выдает, причем выдает верно, но их не хватает

Comment: миллиона ... ? Вы же в курсе, что строка выводимая group_concat ограничена 1024 символами ?

Comment: вооот, об этом я и не знал, видимо оно отрезает то что не влазит в строку )) спасибо за наводку! Есть варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: Читать без группировки и собирать строку на клиенте

Comment: Все понял! огномное вам спасибо, сэкономили уйму времени и нервных клеток ))